# Simple Interactive R program

Tags: r

I'm trying to crate a program which asks a question to the user, and stores the answer to a variable.

For example the message could be something like:

"Give the value of X"

and say the user enters the value 1.

Then, I want to be able to store the value "1" to the X variable.

Could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can get user input by e.g. using `scan` or `readline`.

So something like the script

```
cat("Please input a value X, followed by enter twice.")
X <- scan()
cat("X + 1 =", X + 1)
```

will do what you request. If you only expect a single line from the user, then `readline` instead of `scan` is probably better.

Try and save the script as, say, `"input_test.R"` and run it using `source`.

```
> source("Desktop/input_test.R")
Please input a value X, followed by enter twice.
1: 1
2: 
Read 1 item
X + 1 = 2
```